# HXT: How to use output of an arrow as function argument?

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

It's very difficult to give good title to this question… I'm stuck with HXT
again. I understand what I want to do, but I'm not sure how to make it play
nicely with arrows. Here I give simplified description of the problem.

Function `foo` takes an `Int` and returns an arrow:

```hs
foo :: ArrowXml a => Int -> a XmlTree XmlTree
```

Function `bar` extracts value of some attribute:

```hs
bar :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree String
```

Now, I need to write `baz` that takes a map from `String`s to `Int`s and
returns an arrow:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

baz :: ArrowXml a => M.Map String Int -> a XmlTree XmlTree
```

Logic of `baz`: extract value of the attribute with `bar` and look up it in
the map. If `M.lookup` returns `Just x`, invoke `foo x`, otherwise don't do
anything (input of the arrow goes through unchanged).

AFAIK every such an arrow works as a filter, so in reality `ArrowXml a => a
XmlTree String` type means that it takes a `XmlTree` and returns (possibly
empty) list of `String`s. This makes me reformulate logic of `baz`. For
given input `XmlTree` there may be many strings, every string should be used
to look up an integer and first found integer should be passed to `foo`. If
all of them result in `Nothing`, don't do anything.

Here what I've come up with:

```hs
baz :: ArrowXml a => M.Map String Int -> a XmlTree XmlTree
baz m = this &&& (bar >>> arr (`M.lookup` m)) >>> arr (uncurry f)
    where f xml Nothing  = xml
          f xml (Just x) = foo x xml
-- compiler says:          ^^^ not so fast, boy

Could not deduce (ArrowXml (->)) arising from a use of ‘foo’
from the context (ArrowXml a)
  bound by the type signature for
             baz :: ArrowXml a => M.Map String Int -> a XmlTree XmlTree
```

Not only compiler doesn't like it, but it's difficult to reason about too.

Comment: It might be better to reformulate it as `baz :: M.Map String Int -> a (String, XmlTree) (Maybe Int, XmlTree)` and `foo :: a (Maybe Int, XmlTree) XmlTree`, or possibly some extra arrow between that gets rid of the `Maybe` problem.  Then you just have `bar &&& arr id >>> baz m >>> foo`, which is much more readable.  Basically, if your inputs are coming from arrows, pass those values around using arrows.  At this point it's probably going to be worth learning the `proc` notation or it'll be even more difficult.

Comment: @bheklilr, I've read HXT wiki, a paper called "Programming with Arrows", but it's still difficult to come up with idiomatic arrow code sometimes. Maybe `proc` notation can help. Thanks for the comment, feel free to add it as an answer if you like.

Comment: Arrows are not particularly easy to work with in my experience.  They're weird, there aren't as many good tutorials for them, and they make the most intuitive sense when treated as functions, but all the really interesting arrows aren't.  On top of that there's a lot of `Arrow*` classes that implement more functionality on top of the basic arrows.  I can't say that I feel confident working with arrows yet, but I know the basics of how they work and how to use them.  While my answer below looks nice, it took me more than a few minutes to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took me some time to understand how to accomplish this, because when your
arrow has type like `a (b, XmlTree) XmlTree`, you can really use it, because
of type conflicts with the rest of the API.

Here is another solution that seems to be more idiomatic:

```hs
baz :: ArrowXml a => M.Map String Int -> a XmlTree XmlTree
baz m = maybe this foo $< (bar >>> arr (`M.lookup` m))
```

All the magic happens because of
[`($<)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v:-36--60-)
function. From the documentation:

> compute the parameter for an arrow with extra parameters from the input
>   and apply the arrow for all parameter values to the input

See also this section of HXT Wiki: [8.2 Transform external references into
absolute
references](https://wiki.haskell.org/HXT#Transform_external_references_into_absolute_references).

Answer (score 2):

If you reformulate your type signatures a bit you can get this to line up pretty well.  Since you have values coming from the result of an arrow in `baz` affecting the behavior of `foo`, those values need to be fed to `foo` using the arrow instead of as a typical argument.  This actually simplifies things a lot, but I'll recommend creating a `foo`, then a `fooWrapper` that handles the decision itself.  With the correct types you'd have

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Arrow.ArrowTree
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

foo :: ArrowXml a => a (Int, XmlTree) XmlTree
foo = undefined

bar :: ArrowXml a => a XmlTree String
bar = undefined
```

Then for `baz`, it should be expecting both an `XmlTree` and the `String` input from `bar`, so it's arrow type needs to be `a (String, XmlTree) something`, and here I found it simplest to implement it as

```hs
baz :: ArrowXml a => M.Map String Int -> a (String, XmlTree) (Maybe Int, XmlTree)
baz m = first $ arr $ flip M.lookup m
```

All this arrow is doing is converting the `String` into a lookup on the passed in `M.Map` (assuming this is given in the general environment already).  Then we need a wrapper to feed `(Maybe Int, XmlTree)` into `(Int, XmlTree)` if and only if the `Maybe Int` is a `Just something`.  Here is where the arrow syntax really comes in handy.  Since we're making a decision here it also requires that our arrow be an `ArrowChoice`, so

```hs
fooWrapper :: (ArrowXml a, ArrowChoice a) => a (Maybe Int, XmlTree) XmlTree
fooWrapper = proc (lkup, tree) -> do
    case lkup of
        Nothing -> returnA -< tree
        Just v  -> foo -< (v, tree)
```

Now we can tie everything together into an overall application with nothing more than the built-in combinators (I also discovered that `returnA = arr id`, so you can use that instead, I just think it's easier to understand with `arr id`)

```hs
program :: (ArrowXml a, ArrowChoice a) => M.Map String Int -> a XmlTree XmlTree
program m =
    bar &&& arr id >>> -- First split the input between bar and arr id
    baz m          >>> -- Feed this into baz m
    fooWrapper         -- Feed the lookup into fooWrapper so it can make the
                       -- decision on how to route the XmlTree
```

You don't need to worry about the `ArrowChoice` constraint, all the `ArrowXml` instances brought in scope from `Text.XML.HXT.Core` also implement `ArrowChoice`.

If you're curious as to what this would look like without `proc` notation, even this simple case statement would get turned into (I think)

```hs
fooWrapper :: (ArrowXml a, ArrowChoice a) => a (Maybe Int, XmlTree) XmlTree
fooWrapper =
    arr (\(lkup, tree) -> case lkup of
        Nothing -> Left tree
        Just v  -> Right (v, tree)) >>>
    (returnA ||| foo)
```

The use of `|||` is what forces it to implement `ArrowChoice`.  While this isn't too bad, I wouldn't exactly call it readable and there is too much going on that doesn't really have anything to do with the actual business logic.  Once you move on to more complex situations this is going to explode in complexity as well, while the `proc` notation should remain relatively simple.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! I only can add that `this` seems to be preferred in HXT, it's one more synonym for `returnA` and `arr id`.

Comment: I understand that we need `Arrows` language extension for `proc` notation, but what about `NoMonomorphismRestriction`? Why exactly it's needed here?

Comment: @Mark it was recommended in the docs at some point and I figured it couldn't hurt. You might be able to get away without it.

Comment: I've added another solution, which I believe is more idiomatic for HXT.